# ReactJS, Redux and DexieJS (IndexedDB) - Error in incognito mode and Chrome v69

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, indexeddb

I'm currently learning ReactJS and I decided to create a simple application.

The stack is:

- React
- Redux
- React-router
- DexieJS (IndexedDB)

The application is working. The problem is that when I try to test it on Firefox or incognito mode (in Chrome), I get this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

[image]

Anyone knows why I get this error and how I could handle that? I found that IndexedDB is not available in Firefox and incognito mode, so I tried to make a simple check:

```
if(!window.indexedDB) {
 alert('Indexed DB is not supported by your browser. If you are running in incognito mode, please use the normal mode.')
}
```

But this is not working, I get the error again.

Here is the Github repo if you want to see the whole code:
https://github.com/Webd01/BM

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndexedDB works fine in Chrome incognito mode, so if you have a problem there, it might be caused my something else.

But you are right that IndexedDB is not good in Firefox private browsing mode, although you're wrong about specifically how. `window.indexedDB` is not null in Firefox private browsing mode, but it does give you an error on `upgradeneeded`. I use something like this to detect it (this has some other browser compatibility checks too):

```
var checkIDB = function () {
  if (typeof window.indexedDB === "undefined") {
    console.log("IndexedDB not supported at all!");
    return;
  }

  try {
    keyRange.only([1]);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Buggy Microsoft IndexedDB implementation");
    return;
  }

  var openRequest = window.indexedDB.open('firefox-private-test', 1);

  openRequest.onerror = function (evt) {
    console.error(evt.target.error);
    if (evt.target.error.message.includes("aborted")) {
      console.log("Some other error, maybe quota related:");
      console.log(evt.target.error);
    } else {
      console.log("Firefox private mode, probably:");
      console.log(evt.target.error);
    }
  }

  openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) {
    var db = evt.target.result;
    var one = db.createObjectStore('one', {
      autoIncrement: true,
      keyPath: 'key'
    });
    one.createIndex('one', 'one');
    one.add({one: 1});
    var two = db.createObjectStore('two', {
      autoIncrement: true,
      keyPath: 'key'
    });
    two.createIndex ('two', 'two');
    two.add({two: 2});
  };

  openRequest.onsuccess = function (evt) {
    var db = evt.target.result;
    var transaction;
    try {
      transaction = db.transaction(['one', 'two'], 'readwrite');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Some browser failed here, maybe an old version of Safari, I forget");
      console.log(e.target.error);
      return;
    }

    var count = 0;
    transaction.objectStore('one').index('one').openCursor().onsuccess = function (evt) {
      cursor = evt.target.result;
      if (cursor) {
        count += 1;
        cursor.continue();
      }
    };

    transaction.oncomplete = function () {
      db.close();
      if (count === 1) {
        console.log("All good!");
      } else {
        console.log("Buggy Safari 10 IndexedDB implementation")
      }
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly